# Is dereferencing a smart pointer async signal safe?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, signals, shared-ptr, dereference

Let's that my C++ code has registered signal handler. According to [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) all code called from within the handler, must use async-signal-safe functions. The man page referenced above lists libc functions that would be safe. I am trying to understand whether std::unique_ptr::operator* would satisfy that requirement.

Here's a simple example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>

class foo
{
  public:
    foo() { std::cout << "Constructing handler\n";}
    ~foo() { std::cout << "Destructing handler\n";}
    void handle()
    {
      const char msg[] = "handling\n";
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg));
    }
};

bool sig(false);
std::unique_ptr<foo> sig_handler(new foo);                                                                                                                                                                           

void handler(int)
{
  sig = true;
  sig_handler->handle();
}

int main()
{
  std::signal(SIGINT, handler);

  std::cout << "Starting\n";
  while (!sig)
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
  std::cout << "Ending\n";
  sig_handler.reset();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should be, but please post some representative code so that we can see if there are any gotchas in what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does it even make sense to talk about POSIX implementations and guarantees from the c++ standard? I'm no expert, but it seems like apples and pears. Wouldn't you have to look at a specific implementation of the standard to be able to say anything with any guarantee?

Comment: @super Yes, it's a POSIX thing, I doubt the standard talks about signals at all.

Comment: @PaulSanders C++ knows about signal handlers as well: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/support.signal

Comment: @PaulSanders - I added example code to the question

Comment: @user17732522 Interesting.  The standard seems to be dabbling it's toes in murky waters there, not all platforms have signals.

Comment: @PaulSanders I think the C and C++ standards require only the synchronous signals to be implemented (i.e. signals via `std::abort` or `std::raise`). I don't think any other signals need to actually be possible. And even if the platform doesn't support signals properly, the synchronous ones can be implemented as simply calling some function pointer to the handler.

Comment: @user17732522 Well if that's true, what is all the fuss about?

Comment: @PaulSanders The implementation is still allowed to have asynchronous signals and the standards specify what signal handlers should be allowed to do on all conforming implementations.

Comment: @user17732522 Huh!  How is that supposed to help us in any practical situation?  Justice for Windows, unlike  *nix, it has a robust exception handling mechanism and it doesn't get a look in.  And that section of the standard is clearly heavily influenced by the limitations of *nix signal handlers, it should be more honest with us and say so.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library functions the C++ standard allows to be called in a signal handler are pretty limited, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal. None of the smart pointers are listed there.

And POSIX doesn't know anything about the C++ standard library, so it won't allow it either.

So, none of the standards will guarantee you that it is signal-safe. I can't say anything about actual implementations.

A question would be how you are creating and accessing this `unique_ptr`. Note that neither `new` nor `malloc` are listed as signal-safe anywhere either and if the `unique_ptr` is not created in the signal handler, then how do you synchronize access to it?

Comment: I added example code to the question

Comment: Any idea how the guys at cppreference generated that list @user?  I spent 15 minutes or so trying to figure that out but didn't come up with anything significant.  But, although the standard appears to be being very reticent about this, I would think, at minimum, that calling `get()` must be safe in practise.  After all, the implementation is going to be simply `return my_managed_pointer;`  OP, we still need to see something closer to your actual use case.  Perhaps this issue can be avoided altogether.

Comment: (Because smart pointers at global or static scope don't really do anything useful.)

Comment: @PaulSanders - I updated the example to be a bit closer to my actual code

Comment: OK, thanks.  But there are two obvious questions.  1) does `sig_handler` need to be a pointer (is it polymorphic or something) and if so 2) how are you managing its lifetime?  Does its value ever change, or does it stay the same for the entire duration of the program?  Because if it does, then `std:unique_ptr` isn't bringing anything to the party.  Do you know what an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) is?  Because it seems to me that that's what we have here.

Comment: @PaulSanders I think the cppreference authors know the standard very well, so maybe they just know where to look or which paper introduced the safe functions (note that before C++17 practically nothing except the termination functions was safe). Otherwise you can just grep the standard draft pdf or sources for "signal-safe". Yes, I guess that would be safe in practice with the straight-forward implementation, but I honestly don't know enough about this to be sure.

Comment: @user17732522 OK, fair enough.  OP can always grovel around in `<memory>` if he truly needs to know.  I did search `timsong-cpp` (via Google) for `signal-safe`, but only turned up one, supremely irrelevant, page.

Comment: @PaulGrinberg Your signal handler already fails from the standard point-of-view at `sig = true;` because `sig` is not a lock-free atomic, although I expect it will probably work as intended on typical implementations/architectures. Although, again, I don't actually have much practical experience with this. So I don't really know how in behaves in practice.